# How should I check whether a number is in a list in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Why is my code wrong?

`# let ls = [1;2];;`

val ls : int list = [1; 2]

`# let inList a l = List.exists a l;;`

val inList : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool =

`# inList 1 ls;;`

Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a -> bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you can see :

```
# let inList a l = List.exists a l;;
```

> val inList : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool

So `a` is of type `'a -> bool` which means that `a` is a predicate on each element of the list.

What you wanted to write was

`let inList a l = List.mem a l`

> val inList : 'a -> 'a list -> bool

**TL;DR** RTFM ;-) http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

Comment: That's it! List.mem.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `List.exists` is a function that returns true if the element is one you're looking for and false if not. You're supplying the int `1`, which isn't a function.

You need a function `looking_for` like this:

```
let inList a l =
   let looking_for x = ... in
   List.exists looking_for l
```

The function `looking_for` should return true if `x` is what you're looking for (i.e., if it's equal to `a`) and false otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! It's kinda complicated.

Comment: After you get used to higher order functions they're a really useful part of the toolkit. But you can use `List.mem` for your particular problem; it works like you were expecting.

Comment: Or partially apply the equality operator: `List.exists ((=) 1) l`